# Is there a way to correctly place the overlapping description box in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hi I am trying to plot the consumers vs day graph from the [csv file](https://gofile.io/?c=9Yp3t8) attached here.

I have tried the following code :

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\hp6\\Desktop\\load.csv")
data.set_index("Consumers",inplace=True)
data.head()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data.plot()
plt.title('Daily Consumption analysis')
plt.ylabel('Load')
plt.xlabel('Days')
plt.show()
```

However this gives the following graph :

[image: graph]

So its overlapping. How can I change the position of the line description box to right side, modify the way it looks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bbox_to_anchor` to shift the legend slightly outside the axes boundaries,

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\hp6\\Desktop\\load.csv")
data.set_index("Consumers",inplace=True)
data.head()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data.plot()
plt.title('Daily Consumption analysis')
plt.ylabel('Load')
plt.xlabel('Days')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 1)) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Call `plt.legend(loc=1)` will put the legend in the top right corner.  Other values of `loc` will put the legend in the "best" position (`loc=0`), top left (`loc=2`) and so forth.  You can also explicitly specify the position using other keywords and also make the legend [frame transparent](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/recipes/transparent_legends.html) so that your data shows through by using

```py
plt.legend(fancybox=True, framealpha=0.5)
```

See [`matplotlib.pyplot.legend`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)
for a full description.